# Pass object as parameter before initialialize

Tags: ruby, oop

Let's say I have 2 classes

```
Class Obj1
  def initialize(object)
  end
end

Class Obj2
  def initialize(object)
  end
end
```

I want to init Obj1 and Obj2 and pass a instance of Obj1 to an instance of Obj2 and vice versa. So, something like This

```
ob1 = Obj1.new(ob2)
ob2 = Obj2.new(ob1)
```

How can I achieve this funcionality? I though about using an attr_accessor and passing then after they are both initialized, but this seems a bad idea as it complicates API.

Why I want to do it: 
This is a wrapper around timetables. Obj1 (Stops) is a list of stops (Stop), Obj2 (Lines) is a list of lines (Line). A Stop has multiple Line object, so Stop asks Stops about a particular line. I want to achieve this circularity on purpose. I want to be able to get something like this:

Stops.first.stop.first.lines.first.stops (and so on)

This entire project is a excercise.

Comment: What's your real final goal?

Comment: "this seems a bad idea" - you know what else is a bad idea? Circular references.

Comment: I agree with @SergioTulentsev -- circular references will lead to many issues. It is also impossible to create two objects at the same time, while using each other to initialize. The fact that you need that long of a method chain is not favorable in Ruby. Finally, not sure if you renamed it for the purpose of posting on SO, but method and class names should be as descriptive (and concise) as possible. `Obj1` class shows zero meaning or purpose, while you should name the class `StopObject` at the very least.

Comment: @HunterStevens: mutual dependency is a sign of tight coupling between two types. But in this domain (bus lines and stops), it seems unavoidable. stop has_many lines, line has_many stops. This allows some interesting queries: "which stops are reachable from this one, using at most one bus change?" This looks like an interesting exercise. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I like your solution below for this question. That's how I would do it to prevent circularity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, they can't be created at exactly the same time using each other for creation. So one must be created first and then used to configure the other. This calls for an `attr_accessor` or similar.

For example:

```
class Stop
  def add_line(line)
    line.add_stop(self)
    lines << line
  end

  def lines
    @lines ||= []
  end
end
```